# Dyson fans in ceiling?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fan

Will it be feasible to use Dyson fans in the ceiling since it has to draw air from the back to "push" towards the front?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no physics in this question.

Answer (score 1):

The fans work by entrainment of surrounding air by the jet blowing out of a slit in the ring.  Obviously it is optimized for entraining air from behind the ring, but it should also pull in air from the sides if the back is blocked.  Most fluid dynamics textbooks will discuss the problem of a planar jet coming out of a wall, this is essentially the same thing.  My guess is it would still work if you mounted the ring directly against the ceiling, but with significantly less efficiency.  If you mounted it with about 1 ring radius separation from the ceiling it would probably work with close to maximal efficiency.